# issue in Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to run Decision Tree classifier , the label is having double schema, and value from -20 to +20

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
import java.io.File`

     val dtModelPath = s"file:///home/parv/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/ dtModel"

     val dtModel= { 
     val dtGridSearch = for (   
     dtImpurity<- Array("entropy", "gini");    
     dtDepth<- Array(3, 5))    
     yield {
     println(s"Training decision tree: impurity $dtImpurity,depth: $dtDepth")
     val dtModel = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
     .setFeaturesCol(idf.getOutputCol)  
     .setLabelCol("value")
     .setImpurity(dtImpurity)         
     .setMaxDepth(dtDepth)     
     .setMaxBins(10)          
     .setSeed(42)          
     .setCacheNodeIds(true)          
     .fit(trainData)
     val dtPrediction = dtModel.transform(testData)      
     val dtAUC = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("value").evaluate(dtPrediction)      
     println(s" DT AUC on test data: $dtAUC")      
     ((dtImpurity, dtDepth), dtModel, dtAUC)
     }    
     println(dtGridSearch.sortBy(-_._3).take(5).mkString("\n")) 
     val bestModel = dtGridSearch.sortBy(-_._3).head._2
     bestModel.write.overwrite.save(dtModelPath)
     bestModel
     }
```

i am getting error

> raining decision tree: impurity entropy,depth: 3 [Stage
>   31346:============>                                       (47 + [Stage
>   31346:===============>                                    (61 + [Stage
>   31346:======================>                             (87 + [Stage
>   31346:============================>                      (111 + [Stage
>   31346:==================================>                (135 + [Stage
>   31346:==========================================>        (166 + [Stage
>   31346:================================================>  (192 + 
>                                                                          18/03/30 01:06:18 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by
>   TID = 63510: [rdd_62747_0] 18/03/30 01:06:18 ERROR Executor: Exception
>   in task 7.0 in stage 31353.0 (TID 63518)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Classifier was
>   given dataset with invalid label -6.0.  Labels must be integers in
>   range [0, 1, ..., 44), where numClasses=44.   at
>   scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you gave the classifier an invalid label.
It says `Classifier was given dataset with invalid label -6.0. Labels must be integers in range [0, 1, ..., 44)`.

I'd check the labels, something like

```
df.select($"labels").distinct.show(100)
df.filter($"labels" < 0).show()
```